# Дамп БД MySQL без блокировки таблиц с использованием ключа single-transaction

Tags: mysql, база-данных, dump

Как я понял, ключ single-transaction при создании бэкапа БД в MySQL не блокирует таблицы. Без ключа блокирует.

Т.е. если выполнить команду для БД размером 3Гб, то на 5 минут блокируется всё. Ни один юзер не сможет прочитать или записать в БД какие-нибудь строки. Т.е. сайт на 5 минут попросту ляжет:

```
mysqldump -u root -psdfihebjdf mysite_db > /tmp/db-backup.sql
```

Так какого single-transaction не используется по умолчанию?) Зачем придумали этот ключ? В чём же всё-таки разница с ним и без него? В каких случаях нам надо блокировать таблицы ума не приложу.

Comment: Для таблиц InnoDB надо добавлять --single-transaction, это гарантирует целостность данных бекапа. 
Для таблиц MyISAN это не актуально, ибо они не поддерживают транзакционность. https://habrahabr.ru/post/105954/   
Читайте тут тоже http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/mysqldump.html

Comment: Прочитайте пожалуйста внимательно то что я написал.

Comment: Какая версия MySQL у вас стоит ?

Comment: версия 5.5.x и 5.7.х

Comment: При использовании этой опции, вы должны иметь в виду, что только InnoDB таблицы сбрасываются в согласованном состоянии. Например, любые MyISAM или Memory  таблицы сбрасываются при использовании этой опции, все еще может изменить свое состояние.Для дампа больших таблиц, объединить опцию опцию --single-transaction с  --quick опцией. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_quick

Тут тоже обсуждаете данный вопрос http://www.nixp.ru/recipes/13.html

Comment: Что такое "таблицы сбрасываются в согласованном состоянии"? В чем преимущество опции --quick?

Comment: Представьте, что у вас в одну таблицу пишется поступление денег на счет клиента, а в другой таблице фиксируется текущее состояние счета, т.е. к текущему балансу добавляется сумма, которая была записана в "поступления". Согласованное состояние - это когда информация отражена либо в обоих таблицах, либо ни в одной из них. Если в дамп выгрузится поступление, но старое состояние счета (состояния выгрузятся раньше) то при загрузке дампа у вас будут проблемы, клиент не досчитается денег

Comment: --quick, -q  Эта опция полезна для dump больших таблиц.буферизует данные в памяти перед его записью.http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_quick

Comment: тут подробно написано про все эти параметры    http://adw0rd.com/2009/6/7/mysqldump-and-cheat-sheet/

Comment: Спасибо. Я читал. У меня вопросы уже по подводным камням.